# R Targets with DBI/SQL database

Tags: r, dbi, targets-r-package

I have a targets pipeline which should fill and use a DBI database (in this case duckdb. Both SQL as well as duckdb are chosen for performance reasons).

How can I effectively use `{targets}` in combination with an SQL table.

A **minimal, reproducible example** would look like this, which reads two datasets, combines them, creates a model, and a plot.

```
# in _targets.R
library(targets)

# preparation once:
# d <- ggplot2::mpg |> dplyr::mutate(id = 1:dplyr::n())
# write_csv(d |> dplyr::select(id, cty), "data1.csv")
# write_csv(d |> dplyr::select(id, displ, cyl), "data2.csv")

get_data <- function(file) {
  read_csv(file, col_types = cols()) %>%
    as_tibble()
}

combine_data <- function(d1, d2) {
  left_join(d1, d2, by = "id")
}

fit_model <- function(data) {
  lm(cty ~ displ + cyl, data) |> 
    coefficients()
}

plot_model <- function(model, data) {
  ggplot(data) +
    geom_point(aes(x = displ, y = cty, color = cyl)) +
    geom_abline(intercept = model[1], slope = model[2]) +
    theme_gray(24)
}

tar_option_set(packages = c("tibble", "readr", "dplyr", "ggplot2"))

list(
  tar_target(file1, "data1.csv", format = "file"),
  tar_target(file2, "data2.csv", format = "file"),
  tar_target(data1, get_data(file1)),
  tar_target(data2, get_data(file2)),
  tar_target(data, combine_data(data1, data2)),
  tar_target(model, fit_model(data)),
  tar_target(plot, plot_model(model, data))
)

# run: tar_make() -> runs all targets
# change a value in data2.csv -> tar_make() -> rebuilds only dependencies
```

This should then be used with this connection to a database

```
# write to Database
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), "data.db")
on.exit(DBI::dbDisconnect(con, shutdown = TRUE), add = TRUE)
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "data1", d |> dplyr::select(id, cty))
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "data2", d |> dplyr::select(id, displ, cyl))

# in _targets.R... unclear at best...
list(
  tar_target(data1, ???), # if I use DBI::dbReadTable(con, "data1") it duplicates the data and returns it to R
)
```

The problem is, that if I return the values of the table back to R, this might take too long. Is there a database-aware adapter for targets and is this even possible/intended with targets?

Comment: (1) That sounds like a feature-request to Will (`targets`-author), it is not trivial. (2) When talking databases (just about any of them?), getting some notification or trigger when "something" changes in a table is a non-trivial, though it does exist. Research "change data capture" (CDC), and see what makes sense to you; for example, https://www.startdataengineering.com/post/change-data-capture-using-debezium-kafka-and-pg/. (Disclaimer: I don't do CDC, I just know about it.)

Comment: I have started a discussion around this topic here https://github.com/ropensci/targets/discussions/1164

Comment: You could probably hack something if your database table has "modified" and possibly "created" timestamp triggers. That is, if anything in a row is added or updated, the modified field is automatically set to the current time. With this and "state" in your script, you can inexpensively query for rows changed since last check, and if the return is 0 rows, the data is unchanged. Do you have control over the database table schema?